# Comment editor breaks some URLs

Tags: bug, status-deferred, comments

I posted this comment

```
Here's my contribution: http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/restful-web-services-a-tutorial/240169069.  It seems to go into sufficient detail to provide a satisfactory answer to your question.
```

Which apparently broke the URL.  Here is the link to the comment:

[Is this pattern RESTful? Or something else?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274173/is-this-pattern-restful-or-something-else?noredirect=1#comment561385_274173)

Clue:  What's that semicolon doing there?

Comment: copying the link location appends `%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B` to it for some reason. looks like percent encoded UTF8

Comment: those are ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER and ZERO WIDTH SPACE. Looks like a copy paste thing...

Comment: Yeah, but copy/pasted from where?

Comment: Zero width Unicode characters such as the ZWNJ or ZWJ can be used to append a mostly invisible tracking ID onto an URL. It's a bit of a dark pattern. Proper use of percent-encoding can mitigate any such problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is hitting an edge case with the markdown [space forcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44011/zero-width-non-joiner-allows-unclickable-titles) workaround. In order to remove it we have to rework the comment structure from tables to something nicer. I'm deferring this one for now.

Comment: I think you probably meant to link to [this MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow) instead of [that one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44011/zero-width-non-joiner-allows-unclickable-titles). But see also [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240050); there *are* other ways to fix this problem. (In fact, I just realized that adding `word-wrap: break-word` to that CSS fix makes it work even better; I'll add that to the next SOUP release.)